# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, keycloak, wildfly

I updated my project to Java 17/Wildfly 27/Keycloak 19 and I get the error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap

The library Maven: jakarta.ws.rs-api is added in the library of the project via Maven: jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api:3.1.0

Does somebody know why this happens?

My pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>mainProject</artifactId>
        <groupId>ch.company.mainProject</groupId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>auth-post</artifactId>

    <name>Project Auth Post (Keycloak Setup)</name>
    <description>This project is responsible to setup Keycloak.</description>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>ch.company.project.AuthPostMain</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>ch.company.project.AuthPostMain</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.company.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client-jakarta</artifactId>
            <version>19.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Stacktrace:

```
"C:\Program Files\ojdkbuild\jdk-17.0.2\bin\java.exe" -

Dtenant.config=../e2e-test/src/main/resources/e2e-config "-

javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=55918:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\work\project\auth-post\target\classes;C:\work\project\common\target\classes;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\org\keycloak\keycloak-admin-client-jakarta\19.0.0\keycloak-admin-client-jakarta-19.0.0.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\org\keycloak\keycloak-core\19.0.0\keycloak-core-19.0.0.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\org\keycloak\keycloak-common\19.0.0\keycloak-common-19.0.0.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\org\jboss\resteasy\resteasy-client\6.2.2.Final\resteasy-client-6.2.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\org\jboss\resteasy\resteasy-client-api\6.2.2.Final\resteasy-client-api-6.2.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\org\jboss\resteasy\resteasy-core-spi\6.2.2.Final\resteasy-core-spi-6.2.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\2.1.1\jakarta.annotation-api-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\org\jboss\resteasy\resteasy-core\6.2.2.Final\resteasy-core-6.2.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.4.3.Final\jandex-2.4.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\2.1.0\jakarta.activation-api-2.1.0.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\angus\angus-activation\1.0.0\angus-activation-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\com\ibm\async\asyncutil\0.1.0\asyncutil-0.1.0.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.5.0.Final\jboss-logging-3.5.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.5.14\httpclient-4.5.14.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.16\httpcore-4.4.16.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.15\commons-codec-1.15.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\org\reactivestreams\reactive-streams\1.0.4\reactive-streams-1.0.4.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\org\jboss\resteasy\resteasy-jaxrs\3.15.3.Final\resteasy-jaxrs-3.15.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\ws\rs\jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec\2.0.1.Final\jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\xml\bind\jboss-jaxb-api_2.3_spec\2.0.1.Final\jboss-jaxb-api_2.3_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\jakarta\validation\jakarta.validation-api\2.0.2\jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\annotation\jboss-annotations-api_1.3_spec\2.0.1.Final\jboss-annotations-api_1.3_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\com\sun\activation\jakarta.activation\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.6\commons-io-2.6.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\com\github\stephenc\jcip\jcip-annotations\1.0-1\jcip-annotations-1.0-1.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\org\jboss\resteasy\resteasy-jaxb-provider\6.2.2.Final\resteasy-jaxb-provider-6.2.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\4.0.0\jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.0.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\codemodel\4.0.1\codemodel-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-core\4.0.1\jaxb-core-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-jxc\4.0.1\jaxb-jxc-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\4.0.1\jaxb-runtime-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\4.0.1\txw2-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-xjc\4.0.1\jaxb-xjc-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\xsom\4.0.1\xsom-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\4.1.1\istack-commons-runtime-4.1.1.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-tools\4.1.1\istack-commons-tools-4.1.1.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\external\relaxng-datatype\4.0.1\relaxng-datatype-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\external\rngom\4.0.1\rngom-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\org\jboss\resteasy\resteasy-jackson2-provider\6.2.2.Final\resteasy-jackson2-provider-6.2.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.14.1\jackson-core-2.14.1.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.13.4.2\jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.13.4\jackson-annotations-2.13.4.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\jakarta\rs\jackson-jakarta-rs-base\2.13.4\jackson-jakarta-rs-base-2.13.4.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\jakarta\rs\jackson-jakarta-rs-json-provider\2.13.4\jackson-jakarta-rs-json-provider-2.13.4.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-jakarta-xmlbind-annotations\2.13.4\jackson-module-jakarta-xmlbind-annotations-2.13.4.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\com\github\java-json-tools\json-patch\1.13\json-patch-1.13.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\com\github\java-json-tools\msg-simple\1.2\msg-simple-1.2.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\com\github\java-json-tools\btf\1.3\btf-1.3.jar;C:\Users\maku\.m2\repository\com\github\java-json-tools\jackson-coreutils\2.0\jackson-coreutils-2.0.jar ch.company.project.AuthPostMain
Fehler: Hauptklasse ch.company.project.AuthPostMain kann nicht initialisiert werden
Ursache: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap
```

Comment: Are you running a standalone application or a test from IDEA? That's not really a stack trace as much as an error from something.

Comment: We have in our Project several standalone applications, like an "importer application" and so on, and this is the standalone application to configure everything for keycloak. So yes it's a standalone application. But I start it from within IntelliJ via the "Run configurations.."

Comment: In that case, you need to ensure the `jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api` is on your class path. Given the output above, it's not. Why it's not, I'm not sure. Maybe you need to re-import the Maven project in IDEA to ensure it's up to date. Maybe look at the run config and check the class path there.

Comment: I deleted everything and reimported it and now it works... very strange, before it didn't helped. Maybe I forgot something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleted .idea and reimported everything and now it works

Answer (score 1):

WildFly (and other JEE / Jakarta EE containers) provide their own Java EE / Jakarta EE classes (servlet API, JAX-RS, JPA, etc.). If you bundle them in your application, these classes will be **not** be used by WildFly. Even if the class files are identical, the classes in your application are **not** the same as the provided classes - they have different class loaders. Class equality does not just use the fully qualified class name, it also uses the class loader. As a result, you will most likely get a class mismatch. You didn't show the full stack trace, but this is a likely cause of it.

Mark these dependencies as *provided*, that should usually solve the issue. You will also have to do something in your shade plugin if they still get included.

The same goes for the RESTEasy dependencies, although that's specific to WildFly / JBoss.

Comment: I added the <scope>provided</scope> to the jakarta.ws.rs-api dependency, but sadly same error.
Stacktrace added in question

Comment: Is this the entire stack trace? Because it's still not showing much information.

Comment: sadly yes, it's a java class we need to run to configure the keycloak docker and so on